# Java: Outlook type notifications in systray

Tags: java

I am creating a background utility which show outlook type alerts in systray.
I have been able to achieve this by using "java.awt.TrayIcon" and "java.awt.SysTray".
Now i want to extend this to display an unchecked notification  icon in systray just like if you receive an email in outlook and if you have not checked it a mail icon displays there.

Is there a way to achieve this in java?

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, [TrayIcon.setImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#setImage%28java.awt.Image%29) should do it.

Comment: TrayIcon.setImage is just a small part of it. I am looking for outlook like functionality and some library to chieve that for me.

Comment: Are you looking for something that monitors an e-mail inbox?  If so, I would suggest [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/).

Comment: Not email inbox. I am basically working on a alert utility where user gets alerts on some of common team tasks. I wanted to mimick outlook alerts for this.

Comment: What functionality do you need?  Are you looking for a way to monitor some outside state?  Are you looking for a way to communicate with another process?

Comment: Functionality goes like this: Say team is working on task1, now this application will keep polling for task1 [in background] after some intervals and if any changes are made to task or any updates happen then user gets a pop up alert. This we have already done. Next part is that if user is not at his seat and some changes are made then he will miss the pop up alerts and i want a way to store unchecked alerts in systray so that they can be checked later.

Comment: I think you want to use either `TrayIcon.addActionListener` and have your ActionListener display a window with the missed alerts, or use `TrayIcon.addMouseListener` to display a JPopupMenu, one of whose menu item actions displays such a window.

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates an icon on the system tray.

```
class Test {

Image i;

public void popNotification(){
    i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\My Documents\\icon.jpg");
    SystemTray st = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(i, "You've got an unread message.");

        try {
            st.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class TestTrayIcon {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test test = new Test();
        test.popNotification();
    }
}
```

You can also add an eventListener to the trayIcon to maximize the application window when you click on it, just like outlook. The code is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html

Comment: This wil not work for me. I will have to write lots of code around it to manage the unread item. So after reading item has to go away and multiple alerts have to stay in same icon. It will lots of coding. I am looking for some library to do this for me.